# How to use carriage return in printk

Tags: c, kernel

I using printk for kernel print code.
I want use `'\r'` (carriage return) for printk line clear.

ex :

```
printk("hello");

-> : hello

printk("\r .....");

-> : ....
```

But in using \r, It's not working, just printing strange character.

```
    char input;
    if(input=='\b')
    printk("\r");
    else
    printk("%c",input);
```

Is it the wrong way to use it? and How can use carriage return in kernel?
Can't i use `printk` in this case?

Comment: My compile envio is linux (ubunutu). so, I can't use 'windows.h'

Comment: `input` is uninitialised.

Comment: _for printk line clear_  - did you mean a new line?

Comment: Weather-'input' is just example. 'input something charactor' //ClsForCkkoies-Nope. not want new line, just clear&re-print current line.

Comment: `printk` puts the events into a data structure that keeps each 'printk()` call more or less separate (there are times when it will combine separate calls).  When it displays these records to the console, there's an implied newline between each record, and control characters within the text are converted to hex instead of being sent to the console raw.  I'm not sure exactly what your goal is, but I don't think you can do it with something like this. `printk()` is intended for debugging/troubleshooting/diagnosis, not fancy printing.

Comment: Michael-I checked. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\r does not clear the line if that is what you are asking, instead it returns to the start of the line and prints over what has been printed before.

`printf("Hello \r123")`

would print

`123llo`

Edit:
You could just write spaces to the line.

```
printk(KERN_CONT,"\r%*c\r, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, 32);
```

KERN_CONT Does not go to a new line instead continues on the same line

First \r returns to the start of the line

%*c prints the number of spaces according to the length of the string

Last \r returns to the start of the line again.

You might want to write your own method to return string length instead of using MAX_STRING_LENGTH